# Sorting a list of frozensets?

Tags: python, sorting, lexicographic, frozenset, lexicographic-ordering

Is it possible to lexicographically sort a list of frozensets as in the following example:

```
sort_frozensets(frozenset(['d','b']), frozenset(['a','b']), frozenset(['z','a']), frozenset(['l',''m]))
#result = frozenset(['a','b']), frozenset(['z','a']), frozenset(['d','b']), frozenset(['l',''m])
```

So, it's ordered through the order of the first item, and if the first item is the same, then the second item is considered.

Comment: You should so what you tried. We can help with concrete problem in real code. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Sets are unordered, even in python 3.6+, when dicts became ordered. What does "first" mean?

Comment: Please fix your typos, clarify your requirements, and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

No, frozensets do not have an order, so you can't sort them. Find another data structure that fits your problem, we won't be able to guess it.